# Error SQL71501: Error validating element on a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, table-valued-parameters, dacpac, ssms-2014

We have a stored procedure which calls a table valued function like this

```
DECLARE @PID INT
DECLARE @PCost DECIMAL(30,15)

SELECT @ID = PID, @PCost = Cost 
FROM [dbo].[myfunction] (@param1, @param2)
```

but when we try to generate a `.dacpac` from SSMS, we get this error

> Error SQL71501: Error validating element [dbo].[MySP]: Procedure: [dbo].[MySP] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[myfunction].[Cost].
>
> Error SQL71501: Error validating element [dbo].[MySP]: Procedure: [dbo].[MySP] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[myfunction].[PID].

My table valued function looks like this

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[myfunction] 
    (@param1 INT NULL,
     @param2 INT NULL)
RETURNS @temptable TABLE (PID INT, Cost DECIMAL(15,5))
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @temptable
        // some select statements
    RETURN
END
```

The stored procedure works fine without any issues but the error is only when trying to extract datatier `.dacpac` from SSMS. Does anybody have any idea what's going on in here ?

Comment: Is there any reason you're using a multi-line table value function? They are far slower than an inline TVF.

Comment: not really, this was built couple of years ago and has been working since then but will keep this in mind if we do a refactor on these functions for performance